# Application Not Redirecting To OIDC Authority Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, .net-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application built with minimal hosting model. I'm trying to implement SSO through a provider application deployed separately. Below is my program.cs code that I have used to redirect the app to the OIDC authority.

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<PropertiesMiddleware>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFormCollection>>();
    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFormCollection> userFormValues = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, IFormCollection>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name", RoleClaimType = "role" };
            options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("OIDCAuthority");
            options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("OIDCClient");
            options.CallbackPath = "/Home/Index";
            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Home/Index";
            options.ResponseType = "id_token";
            options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Scope.Add(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("OIDCScope"));
            options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = (context) => {
                    var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    if (identity != null)
                    {
                        var domainid= identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "domainid")?.Value;
                        var roles = identity.FindAll(c => c.Type == "Role");
                        var fname = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "FirstName")?.Value;
                        var lname = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "LastName")?.Value;
                        var domainid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(domainid) ? identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "domainid")?.Value : domainid;
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domainid))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Domain ID does not exist.");
                        }
                        string assignedRoles = roles.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                        if (roles != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var r in roles)
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(identity.RoleClaimType, r.Value.Split('-')[1]));
                                assignedRoles += "," + r.Value;
                            }
                        }
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(identity.NameClaimType, fname + " " + lname));
    
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("firstname", fname));
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("lastname", lname));
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("domainid", domainid));
    
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => {
                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token");
                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }
                        else if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower();
                            if (path == "/home/user" || path == "/offline/user")
                            {
                                try
                                {    
                                    var formData = context.HttpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
                                    formData.Wait(); // Waiting synchronously for simplicity, but consider using async/await in actual implementation
    
                                    if (formData.Result != null)
                                    {
                                        var results = formData.Result;
                                        if (formData.Result.TryGetValue("sessionKey", out var sessionKey))
                                        {
                                            IFormCollection temp;
                                            userFormValues.TryRemove(sessionKey, out temp);
                                            userFormValues.TryAdd(sessionKey, formData.Result);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    // Handle authentication failure here
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMiddleware<PropertiesMiddleware>();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

And i have added AuthorizeUser attribute on top of my /Home/Index method. The problem is, when I execute the application it returns a blank page and on network tab it shows Unauthorize 404. I need assistance in what am I doing wrong to redirect to my OIDC authority for authentication.

Comment: which identity provider you are using? Basically, let's say I'm using Azure AD as the identity provider, then I need to set a redirect url in Azure AD so that when I sign in with microsoft account successfully, Azure AD could redirect me back to the url I set.

Comment: Hi @TinyWang We have created a separate app that works for authentication basically we need to provide that App's url and it does the rest. Its already working fine with our other apps as well as the app currently I need help with. It was previously .net mvc app and I migrated it to .net core mvc.